# список возвращается обратно System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#

```
        private static List<string> GetHardwareInfo(string WIN32_Class, string ClassItemField)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM " + WIN32_Class);

            try
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    result.Add(obj[ClassItemField].ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mem_type = GetHardwareInfo("Win32_PhysicalMemory", "MemoryType");
                Console.WriteLine(mem_type[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Вызываю из списка переменной значение, но оно возращает список.
`System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`

или просто `0`

Comment: А вы понимаете этот код? Понимаете, что делает каждая его строчка? Или бездумно скопировали в надежде "ай, все и так заведется!"? Во-первых, я вам говорил в предыдущем вопросе что вы должны найти нужный вам объект, а не прост обратиться по индексу. Во-вторых, не воспроизводится, особенно, данный код не может вернуть `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`.

Comment: [Win32_PhysicalMemory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) - смотрите описание MemoryType: это uint16. Значение `0` - Unknown.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(mem_type);` - видимо, сперва вы написали так. Естественно, получили описание типа.